# Titlepage bleed in KOMA-Script with Crop

Tags: koma-script, geometry, crop, bleed

My document is using the KOMA-Script `scrartcl` class.
I wish to add a bleed around every page for printing using the `crop` package.
I'm also using `geometry` for the titlepage only (as my institution requires exact margins on the titlepage).

All pages increase in size to accommodate the bleed and show crop marks, except for the first one.
The first page shows the crop marks but does not increase in size.

The usage of `geometry` doesn't seem to affect the output, neither does the `titlepage` environment.
Even when removing all references to geometry, the first page stays the same.

How do I give all pages bleed while still being able to change the titlepage's geometry?

Here's an MWE.

```latex
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,
    usegeometry=true,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[cross, center,
    width=214truemm,
    height=301truemm]{crop}% a4 + 4mm bleed

\usepackage[]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\newgeometry{
    left=1.50cm, right=1.50cm,
    top=1.50cm, bottom=2.00cm
}
\begin{titlepage}
    Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output.
[image: three pages with the first being smaller than the rest]

I'm using XeLaTeX, with XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022)

Comment: use the class option ` pagesize=false,`  then scrartcl will stop to interfere.

Comment: thank you very much! this worked flawlessly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Want to make that an answer?